# Manipulating output from sql command asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I am building a quiz application which has 5 categories. I am saving details like name, category and score to DB. Table where all data is saved looks like :

```
Name  Category  Score
John  Windows    10
Tom   Mac        5
```

On the start page i want to disable/enable categories if user has/has not took quiz yet (ie. if John has already completed Windows quiz but hasn't Mac then enable Mac Quiz, disable Windows and show Windows score).
Whats the most elegant way of retrieving these values from database and then passing them to variable or boolean? What if search returns NULL (if quiz was not taken by John) and manipulating output from SQL Database? I am using vb.net 2.0 and SQL server 2005 and its an asp.net application. ANy help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Sorry the formating of the database look does not give the full feel of it

Comment: So i have 3 colums : Name, Category and Score

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an ORM such as nHibernate. You can specify default values, and in the event of a null search result, you can instantiate a business/DTO object directly and pre-fill it with whatever you'd like.

If that's too much - you can always iterate through a datatable (if that's what you're returning from the SQL query).

Comment: Thanks for quick response jbehren. at the moment i am not returning anything from sql query hence a reason why i am asking for opinions first. Any suggestions as to what can be used to best fit the output? how the sql command would look like?

Comment: use an outer join statement:
select a.user, b.category, a.score from categories b left outer join userscores b on a.category = b.category

Comment: i've had a play with outer join but for my application better was to bind results of select statement to datalist then run loop find values and assign them to variables. thanks anyway